# Counting amount of non-empty + no-background cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file, where only two columns have values (A-order number, B-some text/comment) and i need to perform certain counting:

1- Count the amount of cells in B, which are non-empty -> Did it already using COUNTA()

2- Count amount of cells that have "Grey" as a background color.

At the end I will need just a number of non-empty and no-background-color cells.

Comment: How have you tried to accomplish this?  Where have you run into problems?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I can count the amount of non-empty cells, which is pretty simple using COUNTA(), but I have no idea how to count amount of cells that have been colored. I have loocked through several VBA macros, but they are not my case.

Comment: You use VBA and just iterate through the cells, looking for the `Interior` color property to be whatever shade of gray you are testing for.  You cannot do it with a formula in Native Excel, but you can do a `Find` selecting the appropriate format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't really be achieved without VBA. Go to the VBA editor, add a new module and paste this in:

```
Function CountClear(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In rng
        If r.Value <> vbNullString And r.Interior.Color = vbWhite Then
            CountClear = CountClear + 1
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

You can then use the formula on the worksheet like a normal `COUNTA` function, just type `CountClear(B1:B100)`.

**Note** you will suffer badly if you use whole column references with this function so if you only have data in `B1:B100` select that range, or a bit extra -- just not `B:B`